# Set Apache DefaultIndex for Specific Directory

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

On a website I work on, there is a directory with files like this:

abc.com/parts/df/df001/df001.html

There are about 800 in the sequence of df numbers. I'd like to be able to use a link like this:

abc.com/parts/df/df001/

I know you can use defaultIndex to set the default page to something other than index.html, but can you do this for a specific directory, such that for all sub directories of /parts/df map to an HTML file with the same name as the subfolder?

Or, better yet, I'd like to use a URL like this:

abc.com/parts/df001 (even though the file lives at abc.com/parts/df/df001/df001.html)

I think this might be possible with mod_rewrite and regular expressions, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the [Apache HTTPD documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) - the directive you're looking for is called **DirectoryIndex**. The contexts you can define that are given with `server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess` - but at the same time you learn (from the documentation) that there's no type of regex supported for that directive. Therefore mod_rewrite is what you need.

Regarding the regex - I'd say you can use sth like this:

```
RewriteRule ^parts/df/df(\d+)/$ parts/df/df$1/df$1.html [L,R=301]
```

To be placed either in a .htaccess within parts/df (or any upper folder) or within the vhost configuration. For details on that see the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Thanks @pagid! I ended up taking off the R flag, because I wanted users to see abc.com/parts/df/, not just be able to use that URL. But this is what I needed. I thought it might be mod_rewrite in the end. Thanks again!